# Logic to check unique constraints in springboot using custom validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
package com.assessment.crud.validate;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class AddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AddressValid,String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        // logic
        return false;
    }
}
```

In above spring boot code I want to write logic to check if address field is unique.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should work

```java
@Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        if (addressRepository.findByAddress(s).isPresent()) {
            return false; // address already exists
        }

        return true;
    }


Below is the AddressRepository Code

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {

    Optional<Address> findByAddress(String address);
}
```